# Random container names when building from the same docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    php-apache:
        image: reynierpm/php55-dev
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        environment:
            PHP_ERROR_REPORTING: 'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE'
        volumes:
            - ~/data:/data
```

Each time I run the following command `docker-compose up -d` it creates a container with the same name all the time as for example `php55devwork_php-apache_1` which is the folder where the file is plus the service name. Ex:

```
[rperez@dev php55-dev-work] $ tree
.
├── composer.json
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
```

Is there any way to change this name randomly? Now I want to test a different application in the same container but another instance and the only solution I have is to copy the content in another folder.

What would be the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is a `container_name:` that you can add to your docker-compose.yml ([since PR 1711](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1711)), one possible workaround would be to:

- use your current `docker-compose.yml` as a template: copy it and add a random container name in a new `container_name: xxx` directive.
- run your `docker compose up` on that temporary `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you want random, you want to just change the project name.

You can change the project name with `$PROJECT_NAME` or `-p`